# Can "What" or "Which" be used as demonstrative pronouns?

Tags: grammaticality, pronouns

Can ***what*** or ***which*** be used as demonstrative pronouns (*this, that, those*)?

Instead of

> What colors are you using to paint the waterfall and how are you using ***those*** colors?

is the following also grammatically correct?

> How are you using ***what*** colors to paint the waterfall?

---

Instead of

> What information are marketers trying to convey in the advertisement and how are they trying to convey ***that*** information?

is the following also grammatically correct?

> How are marketers trying to convey ***what*** information in the advertisement campaign?

Comment: In answer to your question "Can "What" or "Which" be used as demonstrative pronouns (this, that, those)? - the answer is "No." The demonstrative pronouns are **this, that, these, those**.

Comment: Hello and thanks! I am a novice in English grammar. Is there a reason why "what" and "which" can not be used the way that demonstrative pronouns are used? Appreciate your response.

Comment: You ask "Is there a reason...?" That is rather like asking, "Is there a reason why a cat is not a dog?" You ask "Which? and "What? when you do not know or recognise something: "What is your name?"  You say **this, that, these, those** when you are referring to, or pointing at, something. "What is **that**?" = "What is the name of **that thing I am pointing at**?" The adjective from the verb "to demonstrate" is demonstrative. In this case, "to demonstrate" = to indicate, highlight, or show to someone."

Comment: @Greybeard While I would agree that the OP's suggested questions are cumbersome if not ungrammatical, it seems reasonable enough to say "I don't know what he is doing" or "Can you tell me what he is doing?". Is that not an example of "what" used as a sort of demonstrative pronoun? It seems to have lost its interrogative quality in such context.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your two suggestions could be grammatical only if ***what/which*** were used as *head of an **[embedded question](https://www.learngrammar.net/english-grammar/embedded-questions#:%7E:text=An%20embedded%20question%20is%20a,question%20word%20and%20the%20subject.)*** in the main question. There are specific cases where the question word can be part of a noun phrase which plays two roles in the sentence. Consider:

> How are you ***choosing*** *what/which colors to paint the waterfall* ***with***?

The NP *what colors* is head of the object clause expressed by an embedded question (The direct version of it would be: *With what/which colors should you paint the waterfall?*). At the same time, the NP *what colors* is the object of the preposition  ***with***.

> How are marketers ***choosing*** *what/which information to convey in the advertisement campaign*?

Here the embedded question is: *what/which information should they convey in the advertisement campaign?*

---

Your re-writing suggestions of the two original questions are ungrammatical because there are very special cases where you can ask two different questions in the same clause [*Who does what? Which should we put where?*].

You cannot always combine two questions into one just because their verbs have the same object. You can however avoid repetition by using parallelism:

> What colors are you using to paint the waterfall, ***and how***?

> What information are marketers trying to convey in the advertisement, ***and how***?

Note that you still have 2 independent questions in one sentence connected by ***and***.

---

It is true that in some constructions ***what*** approaches the use of demonstrative pronouns, especially in sentences where it can be replaced by ***that which***, but this does not occur in questions, whether direct or indirect, but rather in object clauses. Among other meaning of the pronoun ***what*** [AHD](https://ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=what) mentions:

> ***That which***; ***the thing that***:
>
> - Listen to ***what/that which*** *I tell you*. [the clause *what I tell you* is the object of the preposition *to*]

Here is an example with a direct object clause:

> I know ****what/that which*** you are going to say*.

Comment: Excellent comment.

Answer (score 0):

Your original questions: "What colors are you using to paint the waterfall and how are you using those colors?" and "What information are marketers trying to convey in the advertisement and how are they trying to convey that information?" both have the words what and how in the same sentence already. Neither of the following sentences is grammatically correct.

Comment: Your shorter sentences are confusing to the reader.

Comment: why aren't the following sentences grammatically correct?

Comment: The compressed sentences have special punch that could make them better or worse than their longer versions. Better for an Edward Albee play, worse for normal writing. They are more odd than wrong, as they take more time to absorb, not less. And @KateBunting said it simpler.

Comment: The idiomatic, and short, way, to ask those questions is of course "What colours are you using to paint the waterfall, and how?" and "What information are the marketers trying to convey in the advertisement, and how?".  This form works in general: "where are you going, and when?" "What are you eating and why?" (although "why are you eating, and what?" seems a bit odd).